# Exporting to high resolution picture file moves my second Y-axis

Tags: r, export

I am trying to export a figure from RStudio to png or pdf or eps. When plotting in RStudio, everything is fine (all axes at correct place), but when the plot is exported, the second Y-axis is not on the right place.

I believe that the issue has to do with the manual adding of the second Y-axis. But is there a solution for this issue?

```
# Data are frequency over time period
total_floods <- c(7,8,8,8,22)
years <- c(1960, 1961, 1962, 1963, 1964)
total_damage <- c(20000, 19000, 1e5, 1.2e5 ,1.5e5)
xLimit <- c(1960, 1964)
yLimit <- c(0.9e5, 2e5)
colors <- c("blue", "red", "orange", "yellow")
png("out_image.png")
par(las=1)
plot(years, total_floods, type="l", col=colors[2], lwd=lineWidth, 
     xlim=xLimit, font.lab=2, ylab="", main= paste("Yes yes yes", 
     xLimit[1],"-",xLimit[2]," period"), xlab="Year")
axis(side=2, col.axis=colors[2], font=2, las=2)
axis(side=1, font=2, las=1)   
par(new = TRUE, mar = c(5,5,2,5))
plot(years, total_damage/1000000, type="l", col=colors[3], 
     lwd=lineWidth,  xlim=xLimit, xlab=NA, ylab=NA, axes=FALSE)
axis(side=4, col.axis=colors[3], font=2, las=2)
mtext(side=2, font=2, line=3, "Yes", col=colors[2], las=3)
mtext(side=4, font=2, line=3, "Yes of US Dollars", col=colors[3], las=3)
dev.off()
```

I also checked the plotting parameters using `par(no.readonly=TRUE)` for situations before and after the problem, and there are no differences in plotting parameter values.

Comment: Please make your example reproducible.

Comment: The example is now reproducible.